# Can't get Mandrill to send emails from Rails App

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to send emails in a Rails app. It works if I use Gmail, but it's not working if I use Mandrill. I'm getting this timeout error with Mandrill. Not sure what I'm doing wrong. With both Gmail and Mandrill I am setting the username and password/api_key using environment variables. The only difference between the two setups is what you see below. Any ideas?

```
Timeout::Error in RegistrationsController#create

execution expired
Rails.root: /Users/michaeljohnmitchell/Sites/pre

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/models/user.rb:38:in `send_welcome_email'
```

Mandrill Doesn't work

```
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  :address   => "smtp.mandrillapp.com",
  :port      => 25,
  :user_name => ENV["MANDRILL_USERNAME"],
  :password  => ENV["MANDRILL_API_KEY"]
}
```

Gmail Works

```
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  address: "smtp.gmail.com",
  port: 587,
 authentication: "plain",
  enable_starttls_auto: true,
  user_name: ENV["GMAIL_USERNAME"],
  password: ENV["GMAIL_PASSWORD"]
}
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

use port 587 for mandrill, happend the same to me :)

this is because port 25 is sending plain text and port 587 sends SSL encoded emails (which I think is the whole mandrill idea).

I have no idea why they set it to port 25 in their examples.

Comment: I had a similar issue where some emails were going out and others were failing due to Net::OpenTimeout.  Switching to port 587 fixes this.  Maybe everyone and their mother are using 25 so it's just too much traffic on that port?

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few things you can try based on the information you provided:

1. make sure the correct information is in each of your environment files (production.rb and development.rb)
2. try hardcoding the username and password for mandrill as opposed to using environmental variables (for testing only)

Comment: hard coding can be used to test if you're having issues with environmental variables.

Comment: It can be a great idea during testing your development environment. What Naoise Golden probably means is that you should ALWAYS be very careful not to commit any changes to git during testing so as not to expose your username or passwords.

Comment: tip: use ENV.fetch("REQUIRED_ENV_VAR") to ensure that env var is set