# Rails with Heroku not sending Mandrill emails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, devise, mandrill

I am starting a rails app and would like to use Mandrill to confirm Devise sign up and for other features in the future. Yesterday it was working sometimes on local so I thought maybe I would try on Heroku.

When using Heroku's Mandrill add-on it works, but if I change the ENV credentials to my own Mandrill account the emails get backlogged on my own account.

I am testing it using two personal emails, gmail and a school one.

I also use figaro to copy my environment variables to Heroku.

**production.rb:**

```
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
:address   => "smtp.mandrillapp.com",
:port      => 587,
:user_name => ENV["MANDRILL_USERNAME"],
:password  => ENV["MANDRILL_APIKEY"]
}

# ActionMailer Config
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'herokuapp.com' }
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false
```

**development.rb:**

```
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
:address   => "smtp.mandrillapp.com",
:port      => 2525, # I also tried ports 25 and 587
:user_name => ENV["MANDRILL_USERNAME"],
:password  => ENV["MANDRILL_APIKEY"]
}

# ActionMailer Config
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost:3000' }
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
```

**application.yml:**

(I copied the actual username and API key.)

```
MANDRILL_USERNAME: myemail@gmail.com
MANDRILL_APIKEY: ######################
ADMIN_NAME: First User
ADMIN_EMAIL: user@example.com
ADMIN_PASSWORD: changeme 
ROLES: [admin, user, VIP]
```

The `username` for Mandrill Heroku provides me with is `something@heroku.com`.

Comment: If you are still having trouble with this, take a look at [Can't get Mandrill to send emails from Rails App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11356541/cant-get-mandrill-to-send-emails-from-rails-app) and [Using Mandrill's SMTP integration with Web Frameworks](http://help.mandrill.com/entries/21738467-Using-Mandrill-s-SMTP-integration-with-Web-Frameworks) -- port `587` worked for me, though I also have `authentication` set to `plain`, and `enable_starttls_auto` set to `true`.

Comment: are you sure, the environment variables are getting loaded from application.yml, you can alternatively using config vars, have a look here https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that faces the same problem. This is caused by Mandrills algorithm to determine how many emails you are allowed to send in a time period. To resolve it, I emailed their technical team and they were able to increase the limit.