# Configuring rails app for Mandrill in Test environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actionmailer, mandrill

I am working on a Rails Application that uses Mandrill to generate its emails. I cannot for the life of me get it to work in the test environment! I want to be able to use the ActionMailer methods to deliver, read and parse emails but I keep getting an: `Errno::ECONNREFUSED: Connection refused - connect(2)`

**message.rb:**

```
class Message < ActionMailer::Base
  require 'mandrill'
  default from: "My App <messages@myapp.com>"

  def send_welcome_email(to_user)
    mandrill = Mandrill::API.new ENV['MANDRILL_API_KEY']
    template = mandrill.templates.render "welcome-to-myapp", [], [
      {:name => 'username', :content => to_user.name},
      {:name => 'subject', :content => "Welcome to MyApp, #{to_user.name}"}
    ]
    @body = template['html']
    mail(:subject => "Welcome to MyApp, #{to_user.name}", :to => to_user.email, "tags" => ["In Trial - Welcome"],)
    headers['X-MC-Track'] = "opens"
    headers['X-MC-Tags'] ="invite_sent"
  end

end
```

**production.rb**

```
# Mailer configurations

  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :protocol => 'https', :host => 'app.myapp.com' }

  ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
    :address   => "smtp.mandrillapp.com",
    :port      => 25, # ports 587 and 2525 are also supported with STARTTLS
    :enable_starttls_auto => true, # detects and uses STARTTLS
    :user_name => ENV['MANDRILL_USERNAME'],
    :password  => ENV['MANDRILL_API_KEY'], # SMTP password is any valid API key
    :authentication => 'login', # Mandrill supports 'plain' or 'login'
    :domain => 'myapp.com', # your domain to identify your server when connecting
  }
```

**test.rb**

```
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
   :address   => "smtp.mandrillapp.com",
   :port      => 25, # ports 587 and 2525 are also supported with STARTTLS
   :enable_starttls_auto => true, # detects and uses STARTTLS
   :user_name => ENV['MANDRILL_USERNAME'],
   :password  => ENV['MANDRILL_API_KEY_TEST'], # SMTP password is any valid API key
   :authentication => 'login', # Mandrill supports 'plain' or 'login'
   :domain => 'myapp.com', # your domain to identify your server when connecting
 }

 config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => '192.168.11.44:3000' }
 config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
```

Comment: Did you add a ip blocking to the mandrill api? Perhaps you fixed it to your production server and requests from other ips are being blocked.

Answer (score 0):

Check the port you are using to connect to mandrill. It should be 2525 or 587.

I think this problem is the same as yours: [Can't get Mandrill to send emails from Rails App](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11512536).